# Reverse heatmap colors (Google heatmap)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I have heatmap on my project

I show driving path on it.

Here is function to show heat markers

```
function getDriving() {
var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
$.getJSON(url,
    function (data) {
        var marker = [];

        $.each(data,
            function (i, item) {
                marker.push({
                    'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude2, item.Longitude2),
                    'map': map,
                    'weight': item.Speed,
                    'radius': 10
                });
            });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(marker);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    });
```

So as speed is faster, heat marker is more red. But I need to reverse it. I mean speed faster markers needs to be more green. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example of heatmap color.

```js
var MIN_NO_ACC = 520;
var MAX_NO_ACC = 6119;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.785091, -73.968285),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  codeAddress("10001", 6119);
  codeAddress("10002", 5180);
  codeAddress("10003", 4110);
  codeAddress("10004", 899);
  codeAddress("10005", 520);
  codeAddress("10006", 599);

  function codeAddress(zip, noAccidents) {
    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': zip
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var hotSpot = results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(hotSpot + " " + noAccidents);

        var heatMapZip = [{
            location: hotSpot,
            weight: noAccidents
          }

        ];

        var color = [
          "#ff0000",
          "#00ff00"
        ];

        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatMapZip,
          radius: 50,
          dissapating: false
        });

        var rate = (noAccidents - MIN_NO_ACC) / (MAX_NO_ACC - MIN_NO_ACC + 1);
        console.log(rate);
        var gradient = [
          'rgba(' + Math.round(255 * rate) + ', ' + Math.round(255 * (1 - rate)) + ', 0, 0)',
          'rgba(' + Math.round(255 * rate) + ', ' + Math.round(255 * (1 - rate)) + ', 0, 1)'
        ];
        heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
        heatmap.setMap(map);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization"></script>

<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzy0y6es

Comment: Can you paste link?